# $\lim_{ x\to 0} f(x)$ also equal to $L$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

If $\lim_{ x\to 0} f(x^2) = L$, is the $\lim_{ x\to 0} f(x)$ also equal to $L$? If not, prove by an example.

Firstly, I apoligise for the horrible formatting, it doesn't seem to be working on my computer.

Secondly, I am having a hard time figuring this out. It seems to me that you could (via a proof) but I can think of a few examples where the limit is not equal, for example $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Any thoughts on how to approach this?

Comment: Note that under the conditions of the question we do have $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}f(x)=L$.

Answer (score 5):

No. For example $f(x)=1$ if $x>=0$ and 0 otherwise. Then $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x^2)=1$, yet $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)$ is not defined.

Comment: All to easy.  (+1)

Comment: Is there any other example apart from that one?

Comment: @JDel1996 Do you understand the concept from Alex's example? Because if so, it should be easy to construct infinitely many examples.

Answer (score 0):

No, another example is $f(x^2)=e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}}$, note that $x^2$ is always positive where $x$ is not. Using this you can find infinitely many examples.

Comment: That doesn't work.  Did you mean to write $f(x^2)$?

Comment: oh! sorry for that ! yeah I mean $f(x^2)$

Answer (score 0):

Another counterexample:

Let $f(x) = c$ for
$x \ge 0$
and
$f(x) = -c$
for $x < 0$
where $c > 0$.

Then
$f(x^2) = c$
for all real $x$
but
$\lim_{x \to 0^-} f(x)
=-c$
and
$\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x)
=c$.